# Declaring routes using an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to move my route declarations for React Router to separate files and then complete the route specification automatically, like this:

```
// Central array for routes
const routes = [];

// Two routes in separate files
routes.push(<Route path="page1" component="Component1"/>);
routes.push(<Route path="page2" component="Component2"/>);

// Render the routes
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  {routes}
</Router>
```

Although this works, I'm getting the warning that all children of the iterator, i.e., the routes, should have a key prop:
`Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.` But are keys really necessary in this case? From my understanding, the routes render only once and are not dynamic, even though I'm using an array.

*Is it possible to do that in React?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution is to use [Plain Routes](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#configuration-with-plain-routes) instead of JSX:

```
const routes = [];

routes.push({
  path: 'path1',
  component: Component1
});

routes.push({
  path: 'path2',
  component: Component2
});

<Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using an expression (instead of hard-coded/pre-configured children) and because the expression is getting evaluated to an array, React thinks that this is a component with dynamic children and hence it starts warning you with that message.

And thinking more about it, it makes sense. Because as far as React is concerned, there's nothing stopping you from modifying that array and expecting the expression to resolve to a different data set. Therefore it thinks it's a component with dynamic children.

Answer (score 1):

> From my understanding, the routes render only once and are not dynamic, even though I'm using an array.

Even though `<Router>` will render only once, it still is a React component and it's not aware that it will "only render once". The component needs to be ready to 're-render' and do so efficiently.

In order to make sure the component is render efficiently, it asks for these "keys".

---

You can stop reading my response here but if you want to build more intuition around it, keep on reading :)

Imagine you witnessed a thief stealing an old-lady's purse...

The police brings you in to identify the bad guy in a lineup. There are 8 suspects outside the lineup room. The officer brings in the first 6 suspects inside the room. The other 2 are waiting outside due to room capacity issues.

Each one of them is holding an ID tag (the **key**). You take a good look at each one of them and write down on a piece of paper their IDs. You still need to see the other 2 suspects but by law, the line up room must always have 6 people. Which means 4 of the ones you just saw will remain in the lineup room.

Because you're very smart and wrote down the ID of the suspects you already looked at (look at = render), you can skip looking at the suspects whom's ID is already in your list.

I know it's a weird example but I hope it helps :)

If you want more details, the React docs are a good place to start: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#list-wise-diff

Comment: Haha, thanks for the story! :D I was hoping for a way to tell React that it just shouldn't care about the keys. Or in other words: I don't mind looking at the suspects again to figure out who was in the room before. It might be slower but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending props down to the child components without specific ids you would see this warning.

So basically when you say run a loop and pass the parameters to child components you need to specify ids for each iteration in the props.

For example,

```
const a=[
   {'id':1,'name':'x',age:'25'},
   {'id':2,'name':'y',age:'26'},
]
```

Parent Component:-

```
  class Parent extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
      super();
      this.state={
         details=[
           {'id':1,'name':'x',age:'25'},
           {'id':2,'name':'y',age:'26'},
          ] 
       } 
    }

      _getDetails() {
               return this.state.details.map((content)=>{
                     return (
                    <Child key={content.id} name={content.name} age={content.age}/>
                    );
               });
         }
}
```

In above Child is the component where you are passing props to.

Comment: I understand why keys are necessary, but my question is more about dynamic children in the context of routing. It doesn't really make sense to give a route an ID, in my opinion.